# Why doesn't this array missing comma's throw an error?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Had an error in some code this morning but I was curious as to why this parses at all.

How does this code parse?

It is missing a comma on the forth and fifth line.

```
var board = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0,  0,  0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0,  0,  0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0,  0,  0]
    [0, 'x', 0, 0,  0,  0]
    [0, 0, 0, 0,  0,  0]
]
```

Edit:
It returns:

```
[
    [0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0],
    undefined
]
```

My question is why does this parse, and why does undefined appear as the third element in the array?

If this is a duplicate, question can you post a link to the duplicate below.

ANSWER:
The answer is:
this evaluates to an array [0, 0, 0, 0,  0,  0]
and the line after acts as an index lookup on that array.

For example:
array[0, 'x', 0, 0,  0,  0]

which then returns undefined

Comment: It simply will be called like an array within an array. That is to say, access array B inside of array A.

Comment: It doesn't throw an error, but I can't access e.g. `board[2][0]`, which I should be able to.  The highest indices I can access are `board[1][5]`.

Comment: if you do a `console.log(board)`, you will notice there is only two elements in the array with a length of 3, and third element is undefined

Comment: So the reason is: `[0, 0, 0, 0,  0,  0][0, 'x', 0, 0,  0,  0]` gives you `0`, and `[0, 0, 0, 0,  0,  0]` of `0` is undefined, thats why third element is undefined

Comment: The comments so far have been confusing. The line in the middle — `[0, 0, 0, 0,  0,  0]` — is a regular array, but the line after that — `[0, 'x', 0, 0,  0,  0]` — accesses an index of the array. Since index (or property) access expects one expression, `0, 'x', 0, 0,  0,  0` gets evaluated as `0` (the last comma-separated expression), due to the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). You end up with `[0, 0, 0, 0,  0,  0][0]` or `0`. The same thing repeats for the line after that, and you end up with `0[0]`, or `undefined`.